# How to get related entries from a Matrix block itself related to another section

Tags: templating, matrix, relations

3 sections:

- Works
- Discography
- Interpretes

**In "Discography"**

Matrix block calling entries from "Interpretes"

**In "Works"**

Relational field pulling entries from "Discography"

In that Work template I need to display the related entry title from Discography (first part of the code below: working) and the related Interpretes selected in Discography (second part of the code: not working)

Is that possible?

```
{# This first part displays correctly: #}

{% set relatedRecords = craft.entries.section('contenuDiscographie').relatedTo(entry) %}
{% for record in relatedRecords %}

    <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ record.url }}">{{ record.title }}</a></li>
    </ul>

{# And trying to display the related entries from "Interpretes". That's where I'm stuck: #}

    {% for block in entry.compDiscographie %}

        {% set relatedPerformers = craft.entries.section('interpretes').relatedTo(block) %}
        {% for performer in relatedPerformers %}
            {{ performer.title }}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Tried to be as clear as possible...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the wrong variable to get to you "compDiscographie" Matrix field. It should be:

```
{% for block in record.compDiscographie %}
```

Another thing to change here is to add the `type` parameter, as you probably have other Matrix block types in that field (if not, why did you choose Matrix?):

```
{% for block in record.compDiscographie.type('myPerformersBlockTypeName') %}
```

Then you should be good. Oh, and you better have that `<ul>` outside your loop!

Comment: that did it: {% for block in record.discoArtistes %}. Where discoArtistes is the Matrix handle. Thanks!